# Flutter Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies

Launching lib\main.dart on F8331 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../Documents/Android%20Studio%20Project/kotaawan/lib/feature/main/home/product/new-product.dart:37:22: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null.

- 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  ^
  ../../Documents/Android%20Studio%20Project/kotaawan/lib/feature/main/home/product/new-product.dart:22:19: Error: Field 'futureProduct' should be initialized because its type 'Future' doesn't allow null.
- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'Product' is from 'package:kotaawan/model/product.dart' ('lib/model/product.dart').
  Future futureProduct;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'E:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 20s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: You need to add your code if you need help. This file seems to be the source of the error:  lib/feature/main/home/product/new-product.dart. Include the contents of this file in your question.

Comment: Make sure you have the `return` keyword everywhere it is needed!

Answer (score 3):

just add a default return widget inside your builder. Like this

```
return Text("No widget to build");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... ../../Documents/Android%20Studio%20Project/kotaawan/lib/feature/main/home/product/new-product.dart:37:22: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null.

From these lines, it seems like you are defining a function at line 37 that supposed to return a `Widget`, but instead return `null`. Keep in mind that when placing a widget within a screen in Flutter, that widget **must not be null**.
You can catch the `null` widget with a blank `Container` like:

```dart
...
child: someWidget ?? Container()
...
```

**Small note**: When asking question, you should include the block of code mentioned in the error in your question (The block from line 37 in your `new-product.dart` file), so that others can pinpoint the error faster.

Comment: The OP is using null-safety. This won't solve their problem. It's also best to wait until the OP includes their code before answering without proper information. It's also not required to pass a non-null child for many of flutter's widgets.

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _FireData.collection('Text').snapshots(),
                builder: (
                  BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot snapshot,
                ) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final Messages = snapshot.data.docs;
                    List<Text> MessagesWeigets = [];
                    for (var message in Messages) {
                      final TextMessage = message.data['Text'];
                      final TextUser = message.data['User'];
                      final MessageWeiget = Text('$TextMessage From $TextUser');
                      MessagesWeigets.add(MessageWeiget);
                    }
                    return Column(
                      children: MessagesWeigets,
                    );
                  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
onWillPop:() { moveToLastScreen(); return Future(() => false) }
```

Future moveToLastScreen() async {Navigator.pop(context, true);return true;}

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it to Add Any Widget in your implementation like this.

```
return Text("Empty..");
```